# Which version of the compiler should I be using?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am running Flex Builder on a Mac using the Flex3.6A compiler. I have been trying to use a Date object, but it keeps giving me errors, even when I run the most basic files from the Flex documentation. For example, the following fails:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="init()">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function init():void{
            var now:Date = new Date();
            trace(now)
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

I've never before had a problem like this on the Mac. Am I running the wrong compier?

Comment: I've been experimenting with different files. Sometimes the Date object is recognized, sometimes it is not. I've restarted my computer but that made no difference.

Comment: Basically Date is a class from playerglobal.swc which means that it's actual functionality is defined inside the flash player runtime (possibly in the VM but idk for sure).  Please include your actual errors, compile time or run-time and as much detail about them as possible since that will get you to a solution the fastest.  I've never really had a problem with the compiler itself, even on Linux which lost support at some point the command line compiler continues to work without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insofar as using different versions of the compiler itself with another version of the SDK, this isn't necessarily a problem with regard to Spark or MX components, the newer compiler should be backwards compatible, for example I made a new Flex 4.6.0 project and changed the base class of the main.mxml file to mx:Application and it compiles and runs fine.  One obvious change is that the default theme looks more like the default spark theme instead of the old halo, though I would guess you could manually pull in the old style definitions, or in your case using the older SDK swcs you would probably get this automatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <s:Label text="Just a test"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Please post your particular errors, to get more detailed feedback.  Generally speaking it's probably best to use the same version of the compiler that came with the SDK since that's probably what everything was tested with, but for the most part I would guess the compilers are backwards compatible, the syntax of MXML and AS3 haven't really changed only extensions via the spark and fx namespace have been added, but I don't think anything has changed drastically enough to break backwards compatibility (that is if compiler is newer than SDK source I believe it will work but not vice versa, particularly due to the playerglobal.swc/flash player version changes utilized by the framework).

Answer (score 1):

From what I can remember by SDK versions:

```
3.6 is FP9
4.0 is FP10 and onwards
4.1 is FP10 and onwards
4.6 is FP11
```

Always use the highest sdk version you can get away with.

You can download the SDKs from:

```
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html
```

NOTE: GPU acceleration is FP11.

Comment: I've always assumed that I could only use the 4.6 compiler with Spark as the Spark interface is used in the startup mxml file. Is there a setting in Flex that allows me to select the 4.6 compiler AND get the <mx:Application> interface? Also, apart from efficiency, are there other benefits to using the 4.6 compiler? Thank you!